# Distribution of correlation of fixed vector on vectors of n-sphere

Tags: geometry, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, correlation, spherical-coordinates

This is a homework but my solution does not match the simulation.

Assuming vector $x$ uniform-distributed on a n-sphere of radius $r$ and taking a fixed vector $c$ with norm 1.

Because the correlation result $y = c^T x = (Vc)^T(Vx)$ for all unitary matrix $V$, and thanks to the uniform distribution of $x$, the distribution of $y$ is the same of the distribution of $y_0=c_0^Tx$ where $c_0=[1,0,...,0]^T$.

According to sphere coordinate, $y_0 = r\times\cos(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is uniform in $[0,\pi]$.

Unfortunately, the histograms generated of $y$ and $y_0$ are very different (see figures with a random $c$). 
But it seems ok with $c=c_0$. Thus I suspect that I was wrong at the argument that $y$ has the same distribution as $y_0$. But I don't see how I could be wrong!

Note that I generated the uniformly distributed vector following [this definition of spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates) by generating Cartesian $x_i$ assuming $\phi_i$ are uniform on their range. Is it correct ?

[image: random $c$]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The claim that $y_0$ is distributed as $r \cos \theta$ with $\theta$ uniformly chosen from $[0,\pi]$ is only true for the circle (the sphere in $\mathbb R^2$) where we can choose an angle around the circle uniformly at random.

In higher dimensions, $\theta$ is much more likely to be close to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ than to $0$ or $\pi$, corresponding to the point being much more likely to be close to the equator $x_1 \approx 0$ than it is to one of the poles $x_1 \approx \pm 1$. Intuitively, for small $\epsilon > 0$, a region within $\epsilon$ of a pole is a ball of dimension one lower, so it has area $\mathcal O(\epsilon^{n-1})$, but a strip of radius $\epsilon$ around the equator has area $\mathcal O(\epsilon)$.

[This paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ecp/1465224966) suggests that for large $n$, if we take $r=\sqrt n$ to normalize the coordinates, $y_0$ approaches a normal distribution.

Fun fact: if we're in $3$ dimensions, the distribution of a coordinate of a random point on the sphere is uniform. Here are some histograms (I sampled $100000$ points for each.)

In $2$ dimensions (this should match your second histogram):

[image: 2d sphere histogram]

In $3$ dimensions (this should be a sample from a uniform distribution):

[image: 3d sphere histogram]

In $4$ dimensions:

[image: 4d sphere histogram]

In $10$ dimensions (we approach the normal distribution):

[image: 10d sphere histogram]

---

Moreover, generating random points on the sphere by sampling their spherical coordinates uniformly will not work: the way you know that is that when you integrate in spherical coordinates, you have to add an integration factor.

The standard way to generate a random point on a sphere in $\mathbb R^n$ is to choose $n$ independent standard normal variables, getting a vector $\mathbf W = (W_1, \dots, W_n)$, and then normalize: let $\mathbf x = r \frac{\mathbf W}{\|\mathbf W\|}$. This works because the multivariate normal distribution is rotationally symmetric.

Comment: Thanks. However I don't understand your first phrase that $y_0$ is distributed as $r\cos\theta$ is true only in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Indeed it still seems ok with a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and for me, it is true for any numbers of dimension because of radical symmetry. Maybe I should ask "how can I generate a vector uniformly distributed on n-sphere ?" ?

Comment: please see my update in my question.

Comment: I am reading your paper. Could you please explain the notations of the very first equation ? Is it like that call $S=Y_{jn}/\sqrt{n}$, the probability density of $S$ is 
$$f_S(s) = \frac{\Gamma(n/2)}{\sqrt{\pi} \times\Gamma((n-1)/2)}\times(1-s^2)^{(n-3)/2} I_{(-1,1)}(s)$$

$\Gamma(n)$ must be the Gamma function. But what is $I_{(-1,1)}(s)$ ? Is it the Bessel function but of which kind and what does its subscript mean ?

Comment: Do you really think that the area of the earth between the $80^\circ\text{ N}$ and $90^\circ\text{ N}$ latitude lines is the same as the area between $5^\circ \text{ N}$ and $5^\circ \text{ S}$? That's what the uniform distribution of $\theta$ would imply. But this only happens on skewed maps where Greenland is the size of Africa.

Comment: I have no idea what's going on in the paper; I linked to it because the abstract was relevant, but it's really not my field, so I have no idea what $I_{(-1,1)}(s)$ means.