# Appearances of $\theta_k(n)$

Tags: calculus, number-theory, spheres

In a previous [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4819569/edit) I introduced the function $\theta_k(n)$ defined as
$$\theta_k(n) = \frac{S(n-k)}{V(n)}$$
where $S(n)$ and $V(n)$ are the surface area and the volume of an $n$-sphere respectively. In the post I presented the identity with the Riemann-zeta function, namely

$$\frac{\zeta (\frac{1}{2}-n)}{\zeta(n+\frac{1}{2})} = -i^{n(n+1)}\frac{\theta_{2n}(2n-1)}{2^n}$$

and conjectured that every $\zeta(2n), n \in \mathbb{N}$ can be written strictly in terms of $\theta_k(n)$ and some power of $\pi$

There are many areas where $\theta_k(n)$ appears, and very often formuls, results, etc can be re-written in terms of $\theta_k(n)$ similar to how $_pF_q(a_1,...,a_p;b_1,...,b_q;z)$ (generalized hypergeometric function) or $\Phi(z, s, a)$ (Lerch transcendant) appear in many results, and are useful in rewriting and simplifying complicated expressions. One example of where a result can be simplified is

$$\sqrt{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{2n+2}e^{-x^2}\,dx=-\frac{\theta_{2n}(2n+1)}{\left(-\pi\right)^n}$$

One perhaps unsurprising area of mathematics where $\theta_k(n)$ appears is in distributions of vectors on an $n$-sphere. Here are some examples

---

([Random point uniform on a sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185298/random-point-uniform-on-a-sphere))
The marginal density of randomly uniformly distributed vectors on an $n$-sphere derived from Dirichlet distribution can be written as
$$\sim \theta_k(n)\left(1 - \sum_{i=1}^k z_i^2 \right)^{(n-k)/2 -1}$$

---

[Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Probability_distributions)
The probability density function, for $y \in [0,1]$ for the square of some first coordinate sampled uniformly at random, can be rewritten as
$$\rho(y) = \frac{S(n-1)}{nV(n)}(1-y)^{(n-3)/2}y^{-1/2} = \frac{\theta_1(n)}{n}(1-y)^{(n-3)/2}y^{-1/2}$$

---

The coefficients in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1246748/distribution-of-an-angle-between-a-random-and-fixed-unit-length-n-vectors?noredirect=1) can be simplified to

$$\frac{\theta_1(n)}{n}$$

the same appears [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4196685/)

---

same with ([Distribution of correlation of fixed vector on vectors of n-sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2646854/distribution-of-correlation-of-fixed-vector-on-vectors-of-n-sphere?noredirect=1))

---

Here are some other ones

([calculating a higher order derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2886652/calculating-a-higher-order-derivative?noredirect=1))

([Fourier transform of $1/|x|^{\alpha}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1614897/fourier-transform-of-1-x-alpha?noredirect=1))

([In how many ways can n couples (husband and wife) be arranged on a bench so no wife would sit next to her husband?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391734/in-how-many-ways-can-n-couples-husband-and-wife-be-arranged-on-a-bench-so-no-w?noredirect=1)) uses an identity of $\theta_{2n}(2n-1)$

---

Not to mention the multitude of places in which $\theta_{2n}(2n-1)$ appears like in hypergeometric series, Riemann-zeta functions, etc. Is this all just due to the fact that the gamma function is so widely useful? Is there some geometric explanation for its relation to the Riemann-zeta function (for example), or is it all just merely a 'coincidence'? Thanks